# how to use time to index in a datetimeIndex array

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which has datetime as its index (shown below)

```
              ['2018-02-13 11:55:00', '2018-02-13 12:00:00',
               '2018-02-13 12:05:00', '2018-02-13 12:10:00',
               '2018-02-13 12:15:00', '2018-02-13 12:20:00',
               '2018-02-13 12:25:00', '2018-02-13 12:30:00',
               '2018-02-13 12:35:00', '2018-02-13 12:40:00',
               ...
               '2018-02-19 04:40:00', '2018-02-19 04:45:00',
               '2018-02-19 04:50:00', '2018-02-19 05:05:00',
               '2018-02-19 05:10:00', '2018-02-19 05:15:00',
               '2018-02-19 05:20:00', '2018-02-19 05:25:00',
               '2018-02-19 05:30:00', '2018-02-19 05:40:00'])
```

I would like to filter all the value which has time 12:00:00 for example, therefore I am looking for a return value of

`['2018-02-13 12:00:00','2018-02-14 12:00:00','2018-02-15 12:00:00','2018-02-16 12:00:00','2018-02-17 12:00:00', '2018-02-18 12:00:00']`

How can I perform such indexing please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the hour attribute is not enough if you want to find entries corresponding to noon at 12:00PM. Instead, compare your index/date-range with a `datetime` object:

```
dt = pd.date_range('2018-02-13', '2018-02-19', freq='1h')
dt[dt.time == datetime.time(12)]

DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-13 12:00:00', '2018-02-14 12:00:00',
               '2018-02-15 12:00:00', '2018-02-16 12:00:00',
               '2018-02-17 12:00:00', '2018-02-18 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If you want to introduce a minutes or seconds component, simply change `datetime.time(12)` to `datetime.time(12, 5)` for 12:05:00PM, or `datetime.time(12, 5, 30)` for 12:05:30PM, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. However, it does not work on my data. Using data.time == datetime(12,5) it reports no time attribute in dataframe data, using data.index == datetime(12,5) it returns an empty dataframe, using data.date_Time == datetime(12,5) it reports no time attribute as well. My index's name however is Date_Time

Comment: @Victor Do `df.index.time == datetime.time(12, 5)`

Comment: Thanks again, so which one performs faster? or a more preferable in python please? (data[(data.index.minute==5) & (data.index.hour == 10)] or data[data.index.time == datetime.time(12,5)])

Comment: @Victor The former requires two masks. I think the latter would be better, but the best is to test it and check. If you wanted to introduce a seconds component, you will need to introduce a 3rd mask (df.index.seconds == 30) and & it with the first  two masks. For the second method, just add "30" to the `datetime.time` call.

Comment: I agree with you, if second is introduced the code will look more complicated. I recall that I have seen some tutorial of creating a timer for time measurement, let me do this research now. Many thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 2):

You can filter using strftime

```
df[df.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S') == '12:00:00']
```